# get particular serialport information by changing the port value using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have written the following code in form load event. When the form is getting loaded the available serialports are added into the combobox.

```
 String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();    
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();
        foreach (string port in ports)
          {
            cbox.Items.Add(port);
          }
    }
```

In the next step,in combobox selectedindex_changed event,when am changing the port, the port details are updated in multiline textbox.

```
 private void cbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_SerialPort"))
          {
              var prts = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList();
              var tList = (from n in ports
                           join p in prts on n equals p["DeviceID"].ToString()
                           select n + " - " + p["Caption"]).ToList();
              foreach (string s in tList)
              {
               mtxt.AppendText(s);  // multiline textbox
              }
          }
      }
```

For example:
In this program, ports are added into combo box from (COM3 to comX).
But my problem is whatever the port i select, it returns only the details of 1st port from the combobox (i.e. it return only the details of COM3).Pls any one help me for getting details of port which i select in combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Follow discussion over here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/c236cac4-a954-4a70-882d-bc20e2cc6e81

Read Following in that

> We can't get the information through the SerialPort type. I don't know
>   why you need this info in your application. However, there's a [solved](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c53b23a4-12c3-43ba-9127-b74450ab874a/)
>   thread with the same question as you. You can check out the code
>   there, and see if it can help you.